# How to pass an array to another function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, get

I am unsure of how to pass this array `foo` to another function where I need it. Here's my set up:

```
if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 && XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200) 
            {
                var xmlResponse = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseXML;
                var foo = parseXML(xmlResponse);
                dataOutput.innerHTML += foo;
            }
```

`foo = (2,4,Party---12:00,2,22,Eventalist Launch---6:00,2,18,Play Day---12:00)`

JSON = `["2","4","Party---12:00","2","22","Eventalist Launch---6:00","2","18","Play Day---12:00"]`

So I need to pass this Array to the HolidayName variable.

```
function getHoliday(monthSelected,theday)
{
    monthSelected = monthSelected + 1
    var holiday = ""
    var HolidayName = "NEEDS TO BE foo"
}
```

I am unsure if I can move this array without changing getHoliday's parameters. This is because this functions is called elsewhere as well and I cannto confuse the different paramters for each other. Is there a way to build a "get" functions to get my array foo?

Comment: Can you run `JSON.stringify(foo)` and post the output here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to change the parameters of `getHoliday(),` then make another function that receives all 3 arguments, passes two of them to an invocation of `getHoliday()`, and the processes the array.

```
function getHolidayWithArray(monthSelected, theday, fooArray) {

    getHoliday(monthSelected, theday);  // invoke getHoliday

    // work with fooArray
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding an additional parameter to getHoliday won't affect other functions calling into it.

So, you can add an additional parameter to `getHoliday` and use some conditional logic to set a default value for it or ignore it if it's `undefined` or set `foo` on `window`.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the parameter to the end of the `getHoliday` function, like so:

```
function getHoliday(monthSelected, theday, foo) {
    //...
}
```

Anything that's calling with just two parameters will continue to function and `foo` will be `undefined`. So you will probably want to check that and make `holidayName` a default value in that case, e.g.:

```
var holidayName = foo || "Some default";
```